# HDP Sandbox 2.3 on Virtualbox - Guest unable to access host network

Tags: virtualbox, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a HDP 2.3 Sandbox (CentOS) on VirtualBox with Windows host.
I want the sandbox guest machine to access the host network i.e. to access the machines in the company's network that host can access.

I have both the NAT and the host only adapter configured for the VM.

**VirtualBox Network Configuration**

[image]

[image]

**Host ipconfig shows this**

[image]

**VM Network Settings**

[image]

[image]

After these, i started the sandbox VM, but still i am not able to ping a machine on the host network from the VM.